# OpenTok - How to manually reconnect on sessionDisconnected without lingering connections

Tags: javascript, opentok, tokbox

I'm using OpenTok client SDK for Web, and I'm having some issues when reconnecting a session if it can't automatically reconnect; some lingering socket connection seem to remain not properly closed.

I'm simulating a network disconnection and the Automatic Reconnection feature works perfectly: the client tries reconnecting for around 30 seconds and succeeds if the client regains network connection.

But **if the client can't reconnect a `sessionDisconnected` event is dispatched. In this case, I still want to reconnect to the session** and I'm trying to do that manually, so I do the whole thing again - please notice it's pseudocode:

```
// 1st I hide my OTPublisher element (I'm using opentok-react) so it's cleaned up properly
session = OT.initSession(apiKey, sessionId);
session.on(myEventHandlers);
session.connect(...);
// Finally show my OTPublisher again
```

This works fine, the publisher starts publishing again, BUT I then see my handlers for `sessionReconnecting` & `sessionReconnected` events keep being called, so this means these events are being dispatched again and again. I also see a `OpenTok:ReconnectableSocket` warn, and I'm afraid some stuff is not properly being cleaned:
[image: Console messages]

**So, what should be the proper way to cleanup the session on `sessionDisconnected` event so the client can connect to it again?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adam here from the OpenTok Team. You have actually run into a bug that we are in the process of fixing. We hope to get a fix out in the next week or so along with some other fixes. Stay tuned and sorry for the inconvenience! What you are doing should totally work.

Comment: Thank you @Adam. That's great news that fixes will be out very soon! Will def stay tuned.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that the 2.15.7 release went out last week and it includes the fix for this issue.

Comment: That's awesome! Thank you!